# Remove delay between dismissing viewcontroller and presenting new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have successfully dismissed a view-controller and presented a new view-controller, but the new view-controller appears after a little delay. How do I remove that delay? My current code is:

```
 UIViewController * vcb=self.presentingViewController;

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

      UIStoryboard * storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      ContactsViewController * VC=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactsView"];

      [vcb presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];

}];
```

Comment: can you try with dispatch_async in main thread

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate that no need animated transition. Change your code to...

```
 UIViewController * vcb=self.presentingViewController;

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

      UIStoryboard * storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      ContactsViewController * VC=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactsView"];

      [vcb presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];

}];
```

And if you need lees delay try this...

```
 UIViewController * vcb=self.presentingViewController;

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

      UIStoryboard * storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      ContactsViewController * VC=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactsView"];

      [vcb presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];

}];
```